# ios Application Permission denied update app

Tags: ios, xcode, permissions

I have an existing app (available in appStore) that I want to reboot from scratch, and make it as an update. So I started a new project and reproduce all as equal (name, bundleId, xcdatamodel etc) like in the old project.

I want to test if data are well saved when I update the old app with the new one, but when I build it, I get this error from xcode "application Permission denied".

I read that this error is due to the fact that I try to install an application with the same bundleId that already present on the device. I do not understand because I'm trying to simulate an update.

What can I do to get this working ?

Comment: It seems that updating with an archive and itunes sync work instead of building directly from xcode work, but I don't know if data are already there... It's not really practical to debug like this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution that helps me.

- Build an archive an install it using iTunes instead of xcode direct build.
- The other problem was, the first version of the app was built for the first iPad when xcode was available, but the devices were not yet sold. Here is the old -(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator method used :

```
-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)storeCoorditator{
    if(storeCoorditator){
        return storeCoorditator;
    }

    storeCoorditator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self objectModel]];
    NSError *lc_error = nil;

    NSString *lc_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/data.sqlite",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];

    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:lc_path];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    [storeCoorditator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&lc_error];
    return storeCoorditator;
}
```

And here is the method I tried to use :

```
-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeUrl = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF.sqlite"];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

As the storeUrl wasn't the same, the data couldn't be found ;)
Now everything's fine, I can get my data back !